# How to make contingency table for combining several pair of variables in R?

Tags: r

I have several binary variables (1, 0) e.g., a1, a2, a3, a4. I'd like to make a table combining a1, a2, a3, a4 (like pairwise) to see the number of "1" in either pair of variables.

```
  a1 a2 a3 a4
1  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  1  1  0  0
4  1  1  1  0
5  0  1  0  1
6  1  0  1  0
7  0  0  1  1
```

```
structure(list(a1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), a2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0), a3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), a4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

The table is something like below:

```
=="1"
     a1  a2  a3  a4
a1        2   3   0
a2   2        1   0
a3   3    1       1
a4   0    0   1
```

I trid combn but it returned multiple 2X2 table combining either two variables. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a table like above? Thank you.

Comment: @RonakShah I can't generate the table like above using my data, that's why I'm asking how to do it. But I can put a sample data here.

Comment: @RonakShah I put the sample data. =="1" means I just want to count the number of subjects with value of 1 in both variables of either pair.

Comment: Shouldn't a2 with a4 be 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apply(df,2,function(x){
  apply(df,2,function(y){
    sum(x==1 & y==1)
  })
})
   a1 a2 a3 a4
a1  4  2  3  0
a2  2  3  1  1
a3  3  1  5  1
a4  0  1  1  2
```

ignoring the diagonal or replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using `outer` calculating count's of 1's for every combination of column names.

```
calculate_fun <- function(x, y) sum(df[x] == 1 & df[y] == 1)

mat <- outer(names(df), names(df), Vectorize(calculate_fun))
diag(mat) <- 0
dimnames(mat) <- list(names(df), names(df))
mat

#   a1 a2 a3 a4
#a1  0  2  3  0
#a2  2  0  1  1
#a3  3  1  0  1
#a4  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option:

```
p <- rbind(data.frame(V1=names(DF), V2=names(DF)), 
    do.call(rbind, apply(DF, 1L, function(x) {
    y <- names(DF)[x==1L]
    if (length(y) > 1L) t(combn(y, 2L))
})))
ans <- table(p)
ans <- ans + t(ans)
diag(ans) <- 0
ans
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this option. But I don't quite understand the '1L' '2L' here.

Comment: 1L is integer 1.